# Window won't close

Tags: macos, cocoa

I made my own progress window dialog to use in my plugin for an Apple application. But when I try to close it programmatically it stays on screen. The weird thing is that closing the window has been working fine since El Capitan and it's only since Mojave that this issue has arisen.

The window is defined in a XIB file and subclassed as `@interface ProgressWindow : NSWindowController`.

The window is called in the plugin code with

```
ProgressWindow *progress = [[ProgressWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ProgressWindow"];
[progress showWindow:self];
...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
  while(...) {
    // do work here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [progress updatePercentage];
    });
  }

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [progress close];
    [progress release];
  });
});
```

The progress window stubbornly stays on screen. I traced the code path to close and release the window and it is called.

Something else has taken a reference to it ?

Comment: Are you sure that your window controller's `window` outlet is connected to the window? Can you show the code for the `ProgressWindow` class that deals with the window? A somewhat common mistake is to load a NIB that defines a window but to also create a window programmatically and then to have confusion about which you're actually operating on.

Comment: I don't know why things have changed, but I suggest explicitly ordering the window out.

Comment: P.S.  In my own code, I recently found it necessary to add `orderOut:` messages that had not been needed before.  I haven't switched to Mojave, but I did switch to a newer Xcode and hence newer macOS SDK.

Comment: `orderOut` by itself did not seem to help so I implemented both the suggestion of @KenThomases and @JWWalker - add an outlet for the window and use `orderOut` on it and that seems to work.